# Show warning if method description is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, checkstyle

In our code base, i see a lot of methods like there:

```
/**
     * @param tagID
     * @param startDate
     * @param endDate
     * @param estimated
     * @return
     * @throws ServerException
     */
    List<String> generateMaster(int tagID, Date date)
            throws ServerException, BusinessException;
```

Though there is a javadoc present, the description of method is missing. Hence the javadoc is plainly useless. In checkstyle, what do i do so that it gives a warning for above cases.

```
<property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="false"/>
```

This only checks if at all there is a javadoc present or not. It marks the above method as `present` as the javadoc is present. But the method declaration is actually missing.

PS: Tagging eclipse and intellij. I am happy with any solution which tells me the number of methods containing above like javadocs

Comment: "The description of method is missing, hence the javadoc is plainly useless". This is nonsense. The name of the method and the names of the parameters on their own should tell exactly what the method is doing or supposed to do.
imo, you should never stop code from compiling if there is no javadoc documentation provided. Javadoc is only required if your code is written so badly, it can't be understood without it, so why not make your code as clear as it can be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use this for javadocs in checkstyle:

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/
    <property name="checkEmptyJavadoc" value="true"/>
</module>
```

As you see `checkEmptyJavadoc` should help you.

Comment: It will eb available for bounty in 2 days. i will award it then. Thanks

Comment: How do I disable this check in IntelliJ? As far as I know, I'm not using checkstyle, but it's covering the code I'm working on in warnings about this. Too many warnings become nothing but noise, so I need it to just stop telling me about this.

Comment: Where to add this module?

Answer (score 28):

It may be too late for this post - but anyone else looking to find answer, add description to each element e.g.

```
/**
 * @param tagID - ID of the tag
 * @param startDate - Starting Date
 * @param endDate - End date
 * @param estimated <-- this is not the param - should be removed or fix doc
 * @return <-- missing return param and description
 * @throws ServerException -- throws server exception
 */
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :).
Thanks for the contribution. May be you misinterpreted the question: the question is to raise a warning in case the description is missing.  i.e. people during development should see the warning if they dont provide a description.